# d3.js element-wise difference between two slightly different data sets

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm new to d3 and am trying to learn.

Let's say I have a first, reference, data set:

```
    data_ref = { "name": "root", "size": 25, "children": [
        { "name": "child 1", "size": 8, "children": [
            { "name": "grand child 1", "size": 4, "children": [] },
            { "name": "grand child 2", "size": 2, "children": [
                { "name": "great grand child 1", "size": 1, "children": [] },
            ]},
        ]},
        { "name": "child 2", "size": 7, "children": [
            { "name": "grand child 3", "size": 2, "children": [] },
            { "name": "grand child 4", "size": 3, "children": [] },
        ]},
    ]}
```

Let's also say I have a second data set, that can have some subtle differences, either in terms of the values, or even in terms of hierarchy:

```
    data_other = { "name": "root", "size": 24, "children": [
        { "name": "child 1", "size": 7, "children": [
            { "name": "grand child 1", "size": 4, "children": [] },
        ]},
        { "name": "child 2", "size": 9, "children": [
            { "name": "grand child 5, "size": 1, "children": [] },
            { "name": "grand child 4", "size": 3, "children": [
                { "name": "great grand child 1", "size": 1, "children": [] },
            ]},
        ]},
    ]}
```

My goal is to diff the two data sets. In effect I want the result to have the very same hierarchical structure as the reference data set, with an indicator for every element as to whether a counterpart exists in the 'other' data set, and if so, with a new field that indicates the difference in size.
Essentially, my expectation is that the result looks like this:

```
data_diff = { "name": "root", "size": 25, "orphan": false, "size_diff": -1, "children": [
    { "name": "child 1", "size": 8, "orphan": false, "size_diff": -1, "children": [
        { "name": "grand child 1", "size": 4, "orphan": false, "size_diff": 0, "children": [] },
        { "name": "grand child 2", "size": 2, "orphan":true, "children": [
            { "name": "great grand child 1", "size": 1, "orphan":true, "children": [] },
        ]},
    ]},
    { "name": "child 2", "size": 7, "children": [
        { "name": "grand child 3", "size": 2, "orphan":true, "children": [] },
        { "name": "grand child 4", "size": 3, "orphan":false, "size_diff": 0, "children": [] },
    ]},
]}
```

In other words, this can be thought of as the difference between two folders on your hard drive, that have almost but quite the same structure.

Until now I was using some python code to diff the two data sets.
How can this be done in d3 directly ? I'm hoping there is a simple and elegant solution, but I couldn't quite figure it out given my limited skills at the moment...

Comment: I removed the [tag:d3.js] tag because this has nothing to do with D3. I suggest you change the title and the body accordingly.

Comment: Well... d3 offers a plethora of functions to manipulate hierarchical data sets... See https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-hierarchy and https://observablehq.com/@d3/visiting-a-d3-hierarchy for example. Of course, my goal can be achieved in different ways (e.g. with python, as I do for now), or with plain Javascript, but I'm specifically wondering if there is an elegant way to do it with d3. Doesn't that make sense ?

Comment: I know D3, but thanks for sharing those links. Yes, D3 has those methods for creating the hierarchy object and manipulating it, but unfortunately what you want cannot be done with D3. Also, if you remove the D3 tag you will get more answers, because users normally avoid answering questions with tags they are not familiar with, since they might thing the solution requires knowledge of that tag. Anyway, I put the tag back again.